# Is "the" optional in "...with Ashtanga yoga as (the) focal exercise"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, grammatical-number

Which sentence is grammatically correct of the two below? Or are both ok?

> 1. This one is a classic course provided by us, with Ashtanga yoga as focal exercise.
> 2. This one is a classic course provided by us, with Ashtanga yoga as **the** focal exercise.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of the sentences is satisfactory.

**[focal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/focal)** means central, and we expect it to be followed by a singular noun- the one central thing. We might accept a plural at a pinch- several central things- but we cannot accept the idea of an uncountable noun after **focal**.

Ashtanga Yoga can indeed be exercise without a **the**, but in this meaning exercise is uncountable. Putting an uncountable noun after focal doesn't really work.

A particular Ashtanga Yoga asana can be **an** exercise, and that would be countable, but one asana as the focus probably isn't the idea that you want to convey.

It would work better if you treated Ashtanga Yoga as a **type** or **style** of excercise: both of these would be singular, so they would work with focal.

> This one is a classic course provided by us, with Ashtanga yoga as the focal style of exercise.

A better way of expressing the same meaning would be:

> This one is a classic course provided by us, with Ashtanga yoga as the [theme](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/theme).

Comment: Personally, as a native English speaker, even though I don't necessarily think your analysis doesn't suggest the best answer, I didn't hear anything awkward about the statement "This one is a classic course provided by us, with Ashtanga yoga as the focal exercise" to my ears.

Comment: I think this answer is taking things off on a tangent I'm afraid. The heart of the question is whether or not "focal exercise" needs to be preceded by an article, and specifically the definite. You may be right about the word "focal" being non-ideal, but I'm pretty sure that's not what's being asked about.

Comment: @tkp It's not just about whether "focal exercise" needs a definite article, but whether it needs a definite article *in this context*. As I explain in paragraph two, that question is impossible to answer.